# Wrong Output by sum Floatnumber in jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, output

I have a problem. I am trying to sum two float values with jQuery.

```
<tr id='idList'>
    <td class="price" value="2,50">Testsum</td>
    <td class="price" value="13,50">Testsum</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="total_price" readonly></td>   
</tr>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var sum = 0;

$('.price').each(function(){
    sum = $(this).attr('value') + sum;
});

alert(sum);
$('#total_price').val(sum);
```

I got this output in my text field: `2,5013,50`. Why? I cant understand, why doesn't it sum together the two values like: 2,50 + 13,50 = 16,00?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `parseInt()` function

```
var sum = 0;

$('.price').each(function(){

    sum = parseInt($(this).attr('value')) + sum;

});

alert(sum);
$('#total_price').val(sum);
```

Check **[Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string concatenation

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.price').each(function() {
  sum += (+$(this).attr('value').replace(',', '.') || 0);
});
$('#total_price').val(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='idList'>
    <td class="price" value="2,50">Testsum</td>
    <td class="price" value="13,50">Testsum</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="total_price" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```